# Scala reduceList failing because of type mismatch requiring java.io.Serializable

Tags: scala

I am trying to combine lists with the following functions:

```
def merge(first: List[(Char, Int)], other: List[(Char, Int)]): List[List[(Char, Int)]] = 
  first.flatMap(tpl => other map (tpl2 => List(tpl, tpl2)))

def combine(l: List[List[(Char, Int)]]): List[List[(Char, Int)]] = l reduceLeft merge
```

Unfortunately, I get the following compiler message:

> Error: type mismatch;
>    found: (List[(Char, Int)], List[(Char, Int)]) => List[List[(Char, Int)]]
>     required: (List[Product with java.io.Serializable], List[(Char, Int)]) => List[Product with java.io.Serializable]
>    l reduceLeft merge

I understand that reducing a `List[Int]` can only generate a result of `Int`. In my case, I have `List[List[(Char, Int)]]` so I expect that I can generate a result of `List[(Char, Int)]`. Can anybody help me understand what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You're mapping over other and adding `tpl` to all elements of the `other` list of tuples?

Comment: yes I am so that if first = List(('a',1)) and other = List(('b',1), ('b',2)) it would return List(List(('a',1),('b',1)), List(('a',1),('b',2)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of reduceLeft:

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

So your function `merge` must return `List[(Char, Int)]` not `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`
. Also your function `combine` will return `List[(Char, Int)]` as it reduces List inside List.